# Пропадает сессия

Tags: php

при заходе на страницу /photo стирается сессия.
На остальных страницах такого нет.
А всему виной вот эта строка которая выводится в Вьюшке : `<?php echo $v['data']['big_photo'];?>`

```
Route::get('/photo', 'PhotoController@index');

class PhotoController extends Controller {
  public function index() {
    if(empty($_GET['q'])) {
      $photos = DB::table('photos')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('is_deleted', '!=', 'true')->get();
      $photos = json_decode(json_encode($photos), true);
    } else {
      $photos = DB::table('photos')->where('title', 'LIKE', "%".$_GET['q']."%")->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('is_deleted', '!=', 'true')->get();
      $photos = json_decode(json_encode($photos), true);
    }
    $row1 = array();

        $result = array();
        foreach ($photos as $v) {
          $owner_info = DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->get();
          $owner_info = json_decode(json_encode($owner_info), true);
          $row1['date_created'] = parseTimestamp($v['time_created']);
          $row1['data'] = $v;
          $row1['data']['big_photo'] =$v['big_photo'];
          $row1['owner_info'] = $owner_info;
          $likes_counter = DB::table('likes')->where('item_id', $v['id'])->count();
          $row1['likes_counter'] = $likes_counter;
          $s = session('user_id');
          $result2=DB::table('likes')->where('item_id', $v['id'])->where('owner_id', $s)->get();
          $result2 = json_decode(json_encode($result2), true);
          $comments_counter = DB::table('comments')->where('album_id', $v['id'])->count();
          $row1['comments_counter'] = $comments_counter;
          $row1['is_my_like'] = !!empty($result2[0]['id']);
          $dis_likes_counter = DB::table('dis_likes')->where('item_id', $v['id'])->count();
          $row1['dis_likes_counter'] = $dis_likes_counter;
          $result3=DB::table('dis_likes')->where('item_id', $v['id'])->where('owner_id', $s)->get();
          $result3 = json_decode(json_encode($result3), true); 
          $row1['is_my_dis_like'] = !!empty($result3[0]['id']);
          $result[]=$row1;
        }
        return view('photo.photo', ['photos'=>$result ]);   
      }
```

Comment: Что значит *"стирается сессия"*? ........ и почему считаете что проблема в `<?php echo $v['data']['big_photo'];?>` ?   и зачем тогда показываете ЭТОТ код, если проблема в другом месте?